# Parallelize downloads across hostnames

Tags: java, performance, jsp, jquery

We are trying to improve the application performance we are using the struts2,jsp and webservices and retriving the data from service and display response in jsp page using ajax.

This is taking approximately 15 secs my client is asking reduce this time. So we are implementing the Parallelize downloads across hostnames

How can we load the images and js files from different sub host names?

Please suggest

Comment: Your question is very unclear - it's not obvious which bit you're writing, where you're getting the data from etc. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints. Wouldn't the browser be loading the images, for example?

Comment: @Chandrasekhar: Do you want to use some kind of content delivery network to serve your js/css files and images? You could have a look at this article: http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html

Comment: @Chandrasekhar I think you just did something wrong. Using different hostnames is the last resort on the ways of optimization. Can you give us more information?

Answer (score 1):

> How can we load the images and js
>   files from different sub host names?

You use subdomains pointing to different servers.

You can, for example, configure your DNS so that, `images.example.org` points to Amazon S3 while `js.example.org` points to a dedicated server in Timbuktu while all the other resources are downloaded from your "main" server(s) (whatever that is).

Comment: Can you please suggest what is Timbuktu?